# Alternating output between two arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop

Believe it or not I have searched google, the Stack, MSDN and have looked at countless examples of code that give examples of  various arrays. I can get  simple arrays to work with For...Next loops; as seen below, but no matter how I structure the below code I am unable to get the output to reflect so that each the code switches back and forth between each array, one variable at a time. Any thoughts.

Would I have to create an array within an array? Jagged array? I have looked at multidimensional arrays and they seem like they could be the right approach. However, I am uncertain.

Ok, now downvote and diss away! -_-

```
Sub Array 123()
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim myarray2 As Variant

'Let's assume ranges a1, a2 and a3 contain values 1, 2 and 3 and that
'ranges a4, a5 and a6 contain values 4, 5 and 6

myarray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet6").Range("a1:a3").Value
myarray2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet6").Range("a4:a6").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
MsgBox myarray(i, 1)

Next i

For j = 1 To UBound(myarray2)
MsgBox myarray2(j, 1)

Next j
End Sub


'the out put will be:

[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ] 

'how would one arrange the structure of the code above so that the output is:

[ 1 4 2 5 3 6 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this:

```
MsgBox myarray2(j, 1)
```

Into the first for loop and delete the second for loop.

Edit: Oh and change j to i and a little transposing can make things easier for you.

Here is your modified code:

```
Sub Array_123()
Dim myarray As Variant, myarray2 As Variant

'Let's assume ranges a1, a2 and a3 contain values 1, 2 and 3 and that
'ranges a4, a5 and a6 contain values 4, 5 and 6

'We use transpose to make this a 1D array, much easier to play with than a 2D one.
myarray = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet6").Range("a1:a3").Value)
myarray2 = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet6").Range("a4:a6").Value)

For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
    MsgBox myarray(i)
    MsgBox myarray2(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Upvoted and accepted! :)